# Transient incorrect user and group name mapping of NFS4 automounted files on Xubuntu 14.04 client

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, automount, nfs

`Keywords:` 
xubuntu 14.04, automount, 4294967294, incorrect user name mapping, nfs_v4, solaris11 server

I have a Solaris11 fileserver that exports a couple of file systems over NFS.
The Xubuntu 14.04 clients are configured as described in:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Usually works everything fine on 14.04 clients. The user names and group names are displayed properly but time to time, immediately after automounting the file system, the names of the users or groups become:

Example:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 4294967294 4294967294 2 Jul 31  2014 common
drwxrwxr-x 4 4294967294 4294967294 4 Jul 31  2014 doc
drwxrwxr-x 7 4294967294 4294967294 7 Mai  7 09:28 gitroot
```

With "or" I mean, that time to time the the user's name is correct
but the group name is wrong or vice versa.
if I create in this state on a client a new file, the displayed user's and group names are still 4294967294:4294967294 (nobody:nogroup)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 4294967294 4294967294     0 Mai 11 15:17 nnn
```

but as can be seen on the file server, the user and group names **has been set correctly**  .

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup     0 Mai 11 15:17 nnn
```

After couple of minutes the displayed names on client become also correct.

Example:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 myuser mygroup 2 Jul 31  2014 common
drwxrwxr-x 4 myuser mygroup 4 Jul 31  2014 doc
drwxrwxr-x 7 myuser mygroup 7 Mai  7 09:28 gitroot
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Mai 11 15:17 nnn
```

This effect occurs only sometimes and seems to depend on the point of time when the file system was mounted. The duration of this effect is from couple of seconds to less than 5 minutes. Time to time the effect cannot be observed at all.

I could observe this behavior only on Xubuntu 14.04 clients. I have not seen anything similar on any of Debian Lenny,Squeeze,Wheezy clients.

Do you have any idea where to search for a reason of this behavior or how to fix it ? (please do not propose me to switch to nfs v3)